# isomorphism theorem corollary

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Given a normal subgroup $N$ of a group $G$, and given any other subgroup $H$ of $G$, let
>   $q : G → G/N$ be the quotient map. Then
>   $H · N = \{ hn : h \in H, n \in N \} = q^{−1}(q(H))$
>   is a subgroup of $G$. If $G$ is finite, the order of this group is
>   $$|H · N| =
> \frac{|H| · |N|}{|H ∩ N|}$$
>   Further,
>   $q(H) ≈ H/(H ∩ N)$.
>
> **Proof:** By definition the inverse image $q^{−1}(q(H))$ is
>   $$\begin{align*}
> \{ g \in G : q(g) \in q(H) \} &= \{ g \in G : gN = hN\text{ for some }h \in H \}\\
> &= \{ g \in G : g ∈ hN\text{ for some }h \in H \}\\
> &= \{ g \in G : g \in H · N \}\\
> &= H · N
> \end{align*}$$
>
> The previous corollary already showed that the inverse image of a subgroup is a subgroup. And if $hN = h'N$,
>   then $N = h^{−1}h'N$, and $h^{−1}h' \in N$. Yet certainly $h^{−1}h' ∈ H$, so $h^{−1}h' \in H \cap N$. And, on the other hand,
>   if $h^{−1}h' \in H \cap N$ then $hN = h'N$. Since $q(h) = hN$, this proves the isomorphism. From above, the inverse
>   image $H · N = q^{−1}(q(H))$ has cardinality
>   $\operatorname{card} H · N = |\ker \ q| · |q(H)| = |N| · |H/(H \cap N)| =
> \frac{|N| · |H|}{|H \cap N|}$

I am not sure how we can proceed from $|N| · |H/(H ∩ N)|$ to $\frac{|N| · |H|}{|H ∩ N|}$.

Answer (score 4):

$H\cap N$ is normal in $H$. Each coset of $H\cap N$ in $H$ has cardinality $|H\cap N|$, and the cosets of $H\cap N$ partition $H$, so there are $\dfrac{|H|}{|H\cap N|}$ of these cosets. But these cosets are precisely the elements of $H/(H\cap N)$, so $|H/(H\cap N)|=\dfrac{|H|}{|H\cap N|}$.